# How can I use Either.shouldBeRight matcher in recent versions of kotest?

Tags: deprecated, kotest

I have a project using `kotest-assertions-arrow v1.0.3`.
I have a code using `shouldBeRight`:

```java
    obj.shouldBeRight { value ->
        assertThat(value.blahblahblah, equalTo(xyz))
    }
```

`shouldBeRight` is marked as deprecated in that version so I am trying to update it.
I am unable to find any indication on how I should to that (both on web on stackoverflow).
Trying to upgrade the lib version, I have an error saying that even the import of "io.kotest" is not available.
I am using `arrow-core v1.1.3` if it helps.
In addition to that, I can say that I found [this page](https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/arrow.html) saying that `either.shouldBeRight` is still there in `v1.3.3` so I am totally lost.
Can someone enlighten me on how to fix this situation?
Regards

Comment: Looking at the [repository](https://github.com/kotest/kotest-extensions-arrow) doesn't make me think `shouldBeRight` is deprecated. Could you post your build.gradle configuration or exactly which dependencies you are using?

Comment: Hi @LeoColman, I think a change in packages happened from the version I am using (v.1.0.3). The shouldBeRight used in the code are the ones that in v1.0.3 were present in io.kotest.assertions.arrow.either
There is another one in io.kotest.assertions.arrow.core that is not deprecated, but has a different signature

Comment: `shouldBeRight` does return the value tho, so maybe `obj.shouldBeRight().blahblahblah shouldBe xyz` does the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The `shouldBeRight` that accepts a lambda is deprecated, because the `shouldBeRight()` without a lambda uses contracts to return you the value.

So instead of

`e.shouldBeRight { r -> ... }`

Simply do

```
val r = e.shouldBeRight()
r...
```

Or

```
e.shouldBeRight().apply {
  this....
}
```

Or as @leocolman says in the comments, you can just chain operations.

```
e.shouldBeRight().shouldBe....
```